# Spring Integration Poller dropping messages

Tags: spring-integration

I want to send the messages received from a jms queue to a spring pub sub channel in order to forward the same message to two destinations. The poller was working fine for a direct channel but is dropping messages when posting to pub sub channel. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-name="queue-name" channel="jmsChannel" extract-payload="false" acknowledge="transacted">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="5" fixed-delay="1000"></int:poller>
                </int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="jmsChannel" task-executor="executor" />              
        
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>
    
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter  connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="jmsChannel"  destination-name="sample-q" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of a pub/sub channel is similar to a JMS topic with no durable subscriptions; if there are no subscribers, the message is dropped.

Comment: Edited my post to show the subscriber. There are two subscribers, I have removed one for testing but even with the one, only 2 out 5 messages are being sent out.

Comment: It makes no sense to me; DEBUG logging is always your friend.

Comment: Ok I can do that , I was wondering if I am doing something theoretically incorrect and might need to use a bridge to connect the jms channel with pubsub. I will enable debug and stay with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on this. Since I trusted the solution after your reply, I tried deploying it on the server with jndi connection to mq server. On my machine, the poller would just print ‘poll resulted in message’ for 2 out of 5 messages. On server it is working just fine. I am guessing  something with the way I am connecting to mq in my machine is different than the servers. I will try to look into it from that perspective.